# Uploading file into separate table with Oracle APEX 5.1

Tags: oracle, plsql, blob, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a simple Interactive Grid with modal form on table Project which has a FK to my blob storage table:

```
  CREATE TABLE "PROJECT" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(7,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "FILE_CONTENT_ID" NUMBER(7,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_PROJ_FILE_CONTENT_ID" FOREIGN KEY ("FILE_CONTENT_ID")
      REFERENCES "FILE_CONTENT" ("ID") ENABLE 
   )

  CREATE TABLE "FILE_CONTENT" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(7,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CONTENT_FILE_NAME" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CONTENT_SIZE" NUMBER(14,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LAST_CHANGED" TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CONTENT" BLOB DEFAULT empty_blob () NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "COMMENTS" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_FILE_CONTENT" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
   )
```

In modal edit project form I want to upload file and save it in FILE_CONTENT table and then link it to the PROJECT record which editing in same modal. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

First, i would place a project_id foreign key in your FILE_CONTENT table. And not the other way arround.

When you link to your model page, pass the project_id of the row to your modal page, put it in a page item.

While inserting a new record in your FILE_CONTENT, you can use the value in your page item to link the BLOB to your project.

Comment: My FILE_CONTENT table stores various files in my base. Not only presented in PROJECT table. So, i have to implement it like here.

Comment: When  inserting a row into you FILE_CONTENT, return your file_content_id. You have your project_id in your modal page. Update the project row and set the file_content_id = to your returned id.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But how to implement it in APEX? I guess I need a pl/sql script which binds my data after inserting. But where should I call it from my form.